# How to access webcam stream by ID on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, opencv, webcam

I am working with two webcams, currently using Python and OpenCV.  The system is set up in a way that one camera is on the right and one camera is on the left.  For the system to work correctly, knowing which camera is in which position is required.

The following is a way to stream video from the two webcams at once:

```
camera1 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
camera2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

However, this is not ideal for me since there is a possibility that the left and right camera would switch index if they are unplugged and re-plugged.  Is there a way, through OpenCV or otherwise, to open a video stream from a camera based on some sort of camera ID?

For a follow up question, although it would not be ideal, I would be ok with having to always plug each camera into specific USB ports.  Is there a way to stream a camera from a designated port?  For the VideoCapture function I mentioned earlier, is the index based on USB port or is it arbitrary?  If the index assignment is consistent (i.e. the lowest active USB port always gets assigned 0, etc.), then this could be a solution to my problem.  Through my testing this seems to be the case, but I would like to be sure.